# Python 3.4 - How to 'run' another script python script continuously, How to pass http get / post to socket

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

This question is two-fold.

**1.** So I need to run code for a socket server that's all defined and created in another.py, Clicking run on PyCharm works just fine, but if you `exec()` the file it just runs the bottom part of the code.
There are a few answers here but they are conflicting and for Python 2.
From what I can gather there are three ways:

**-** `Execfile()`, Which I think is Python 2 code.

**-** `os.system()` (But I've seen it be said that it's not correct to pass to the OS for this)

**-** And `subprocess.Popen`  (unsure how to use this either)

I need this to run in the background, it is used to create threads for sockets for the recv portion of the overall program and listen on those ports so I can input commands to a router.

This is the complete code in question:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading
import time

QUIT = False


class ClientThread(threading.Thread):  # Class that implements the client threads in this server
    def __init__(self, client_sock):  # Initialize the object, save the socket that this thread will use.
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client_sock

    def run(self):  # Thread's main loop. Once this function returns, the thread is finished and dies.
        global QUIT  # Need to declare QUIT as global, since the method can change it

        done = False
        cmd = self.readline()  # Read data from the socket and process it
        while not done:
            if 'quit' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye. Server shut down')
                QUIT = True
                done = True
            elif 'bye' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye. Thread closed')
                done = True
            else:
                self.writeline(self.name)
                cmd = self.readline()

        self.client.close()  # Make sure socket is closed when we're done with it
        return

    def readline(self):  # Helper function, read up to 1024 chars from the socket, and returns them as a string
        result = self.client.recv(1024)
        if result is not None:  # All letters in lower case and without and end of line markers
            result = result.strip().lower().decode('ascii')
        return result

    def writeline(self, text):  # Helper func, writes the given string to the socket with and end of line marker at end
        self.client.send(text.strip().encode("ascii") + b'\n')


class Server:  # Server class. Opens up a socket and listens for incoming connections.
    def __init__(self):  # Every time a new connection arrives, new thread object is created and
        self.sock = None  # defers the processing of the connection to it
        self.thread_list = []

    def run(self):  # Server main loop: Creates the server (incoming) socket, listens > creates thread to handle it
        all_good = False
        try_count = 0  # Attempt to open the socket
        while not all_good:
            if 3 < try_count:  # Tried more than 3 times without success, maybe post is in use by another program
                sys.exit(1)
            try:
                self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Create the socket
                port = 80
                self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))  # Bind to the interface and port we want to listen on
                self.sock.listen(5)
                all_good = True
                break
            except socket.error:
                print('Socket connection error... Waiting 10 seconds to retry.')
                del self.sock
                time.sleep(10)
                try_count += 1

        print('Server is listening for incoming connections.')
        print('Try to connect through the command line with:')
        print('telnet localhost 80')
        print('and then type whatever you want.')
        print()
        print("typing 'bye' finishes the thread. but not the server",)
        print("eg. you can quit telnet, run it again and get a different ",)
        print("thread name")
        print("typing 'quit' finishes the server")

        try:
            while not QUIT:
                try:
                    self.sock.settimeout(0.500)
                    client = self.sock.accept()[0]
                except socket.timeout:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if QUIT:
                        print('Received quit command. Shutting down...')
                        break
                    continue
                new_thread = ClientThread(client)
                print('Incoming Connection. Started thread ',)
                print(new_thread.getName())
                self.thread_list.append(new_thread)
                new_thread.start()
                for thread in self.thread_list:
                    if not thread.isAlive():
                        self.thread_list.remove(thread)
                        thread.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Ctrl+C pressed... Shutting Down')
        except Exception as err:
            print('Exception caught: %s\nClosing...' % err)
        for thread in self.thread_list:
            thread.join(1.0)
            self.sock.close()

if "__main__" == __name__:
    server = Server()
    server.run()

print('Terminated')
```

Notes:
This is created in Python 3.4
I use Pycharm as my IDE.
One part of a whole.

**2.** So I'm creating a lightning detection system and this is how I expect it to be done:

**-** Listen to the port on the router forever
The above is done, but the issue with this is described in question 1.

**-** Pull numbers from a text file for sending text message
Completed this also.

**-** Send http get / post to port on the router
The issue with this is that i'm unsure how the router will act if I send this in binary form, I suspect it wont matter, the input commands for sending over GSM are specific. Some clarification may be needed at some point.

**-** Recieve reply from router and exception manage

**-** Listen for relay trip for alarm on severe or close strike warning.

**-** If tripped, send messages to phones in storage from text file
This would be the http get / post that's sent.

**-** Wait for reply from router to indicate messages have been sent, exception handle if it's not the case

**-** Go back to start

There are a few issues I'd like some background knowledge on that is proving hard to find via the old Google and here on the answers in stack.

- How do I grab the receive data from the router from another process running in another file? I guess I can write into a text file and call that data but i'd rather not.
- How to multi-process and which method to use.
- How to send http get / post to socket on router, post needed occording to the router manual is as follows: e.g. `"http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/sms_send?number=0037061212345&text=test"`

Notes: Using Sockets, threading, sys and time on Python 3.4/Pycharm IDE.
Lightning detector used is LD-250 with RLO Relay attached.
RUT500 Teltonica router used.

Any direction/comments, errors spotted, anything i'm drastically missing would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance :D constructive criticism is greatly encouraged!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for the first part none of those suggested in the OP were my answer. Running the script as is from `os.system()`, `exec()` without declaring a new socket object just ran from `__name__`, this essentially just printed out "terminated", to get around this was simple. As everything was put into a classes already, all I had to do is create a new thread. This is how it was done:

`import Socketthread2
new_thread = Socketthread2.Server()  # Effectively declaring a new server class object.

new_thread.run()`

This allowed the script to run from the beginning by initialising the code from the start in Socket, which is also a class of Clientthread, so that was also run too. Running this at the start of the parent program allowed this to run in the background, then continue with the new code in parent while the rest of the script was continuously active.